# very high level embedded Python in C / C++ application is not using Python from activated venv environment

Tags: python, c++, c

I followed the official Python documentation to do a very high-level Python runtime embedding in my C or C++ application.

- https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\n"
                       "print(sys.path)\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, always the basic python installation form operating system gets loaded, even when I activate a (venv) Python environment before I compile and run my C or C++ code.

I am not sure, if the changes I have to do are in the embedding code itself, or in the compile command below.

This is the compile command for the C++ code I embedded:

```bash
g++ -march=native  -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -mfpmath=both -fopenmp -m64 -std=c++11 -o project `python3-config --cflags --embed` main.cpp `python3-config --ldflags --embed`
```

This is the minimal C compiler command that causes the same trouble.
For a demonstration of the problem, please activate your python environment and compile the code from above.

```bash
gcc `python3-config --cflags --embed` main.c `python3-config --ldflags --embed`
```

Run the code:

```bash
./a.out
```

Now, fire up a python shell, run the same command.

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You will realize that the path output differs.

Any help on how to overcome this issue is welcome.

Comment: looks like you are using c++ not c

Comment: the pyton/c api works for c and c++
this is not the problem.

Comment: please tag the language you are using

Comment: Normally, that would require a [mcve], but you fixed it already, it seems.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt you right. I put the code there. Not only linked it.